# Why is "content not found" when loading magnific popup on page load?

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

When opening the magnific popup on load I am getting the translucent overlay but text inside saying "Content not found"
Why is this?

In the console the elements inside #test-modal are greyed out.

HTML

```
<div id="test-modal" class="mfp-hide subscribe__popup">
    <div class="subscribe--popup--wrapper">
       <p>Content here</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        $.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
                src: 'test-modal',
            },
            type: 'inline',
            preloader: true,
            modal: true,
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Should it not be `src: '#test-modal'`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `src: '#test-modal',` or `src: $('#test-modal'),` both will work.

Note : In `src` it's value can be `HTML string, jQuery object, or CSS selector`.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        $.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
                src: $('#test-modal'),
            },
            type: 'inline',
            preloader: true,
            modal: true,
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

<div id="test-modal" class="mfp-hide subscribe__popup">
    <div class="subscribe--popup--wrapper">
       <p>Content here</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change `src: 'test-model'` to `src: '#test-model'`.

As per the magnific documentation, the text should be

> can be a HTML string, jQuery object, or CSS selector